# How to create a box with caption and label like a float?

Tags: floats, boxes, labels

I want to create a box (in which I put extra information for the reader) that behaves like a float. In other words, it should have a caption (outside of the box that says `Box 1: Here is my box caption`) and label that I can refer to with `\cref` like any other float.

Most of the solutions using `\fbox`, `\framebox`, `\usepackage{framed}` are all creating the box, but not about the caption and the label.

How to accomplish a floating box?

Comment: If you want a non-float, use `\captionof` macro from the `caption` package.  However, there is no reason you can't put a box around the content of a float figure.

Comment: Does `\captionof` has a `box` option? (It does not from my experimentation). I want the caption to say `Box 1: blah`, and ideally, the `\cref` from the `cref` package to intelligently refer to the float as a `Box`.

Answer (score 6):

First as a non-float.  Then, as a float.  EDITED to put caption outside of box.  EDITED to introduce new float, `InfoBox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx,newfloat}
\DeclareCaptionType{InfoBox}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=8pt\relax
\fboxrule=2pt\relax
\begin{center}
\fbox{\centering
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}}\par
  \captionof{InfoBox}{Here is my caption\label{fg:A}}
\end{center}
\begin{InfoBox}[ht]
\centering
\fbox{\centering\medskip
  \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-B}}\par
  \caption{Here is my caption\label{fg:B}}  
\end{InfoBox}
In boxes \ref{fg:A} and \ref{fg:B}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I actually want the caption to say `Box 1: here's my caption`, and the caption to be outside of the box. In other words, I want the box itself to behave like a float, not to have a float inside the box.

Comment: @Heisenberg I edited to place caption outside of box.  But am I to understand that you want the float called "Box"?  If so, would that be in addition to figures and tables elsewhere in the document, or in lieu of figures?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It would be in addition to figures and tables, i.e. an additional type of float. It's very common in policy documents, e.g. [this 2015 World Investment Report](http://unctad.org/en/PublicationsLibrary/wir2015_en.pdf), box II.1, page 52 of 253

Comment: @Heisenberg Please see revision.

Comment: It works! I learned about the creating a new float type. It seems that one can't create a float type called `Box` though, correct? That's rather not ideal...

Comment: @Heisenberg  Apparently, the macro `\Box` is already defined (I believe it is a math symbol).  If one was willing to overwrite it, one could probably `\let\Box\relax` and then define a new caption named `Box`...but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Any way to automatically add `\fbox` to the environment?

Comment: @JesseKnight If you mean to the `InfoBox` environment, I don't think so, but you certainly could create a macro like `\includegraphics` that puts a box around an imported image.