# Create a box with the caption "Box"?

Tags: floats, captions, boxes

The question [How to create a box with caption and label like a float?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306568/how-to-create-a-box-with-caption-and-label-like-a-float) explains perfectly what I need except for one thing; they use the custom caption "InfoBox". How can I use the caption "Box" and avoid the error "Command \Box already defined."?

Comment: You should take a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer you mention uses undocumented commands. Better to declare the new float type explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,graphicx,newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
  fileext=lob,
  listname={List of Boxes},
  name=Box,
  placement=htp,
]{BOX}

\begin{document}

\begin{BOX}[ht]
\centering

\fbox{\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-b}}

\caption{Here is my caption\label{box:b}}

\end{BOX}

In box \ref{box:b}...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tcolorbox` do suit your needs (check the documentation for further customizations):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter,list inside=mybox]{mybox}[2][]{%
    title={Box~\thetcbcounter:~#2},
    #1,
    halign title=center,
    sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily\large,coltitle=black,titlerule=0pt,
    colbacktitle=white,
    colback=white,
    drop fuzzy shadow
}


\begin{document}

\tcblistof[\section*]{mybox}{List of boxes}


\begin{mybox}{An mybox}
That's it.
\end{mybox}


\end{document}
```